# How can I transfer a process from a terminal on my linux PC to an SSH portal terminal on the other side of my house?

Tags: ssh, webserver, zorin

I am running a server on my Linux PC, and every once in awhile I have to change things, or fix things through the terminal. Whenever I do that I have to go to the other side of the house, to fix the problem, and whatnot. I set up an SSH portal, so I could easily do this on my laptop, from wherever I needed to be, but whenever I do that I need to restart the process, and when I close my laptop it stops the process. I guess what I am asking is how to move the process from the terminal on the PC to the SSH portal without stopping or restarting it and move it back again afterwards.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Do you mind elaborating on your setup a bit? It sounds like you have one Linux machine and a second machine (your laptop?) that you're using to SSH into the first machine. Are both computers running Linux? Are they on the same network?

Comment: Assuming "the process" is something you started manually, try to use `screen` or `tmux`, and start "the process" from inside a screen or tmux session. You can then attach to this session either from a terminal, or via ssh.

Comment: Yes the pc is running linux and they are both on the same network but the laptop has windows running on it. I will look into screen or tmux however to see if that will help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## `screen` or `tmux`

`screen` or `tmux` are the tool that where created for this exact problem.

## `xvnc`

You could also use `xvnc`, to share your entire graphical desktop.

`xvnc` works the same as the MS-Windows vnc-server. It shares the real X11 display (the one connected to hardware). Other vnc-servers for X11 create a virtual display (not connected to hardware).

`xvnc` will run on most Unixes, that have an X11 desktop.

The other end of the connection, can be Gnu/Linux, other Unix, Microsoft's windows, Android, there is even a web based client.

Comment: I will look into screen or tmux but doesn't xvnc only work between two linux computers. Thanks

Comment: xvnc runs on any X11 system. X11 runs on most Unixes (including Gnu/Linux). I have run X11 on MS-Windows, so it may also run on it, but only to share the X11 session. But on MS-windows you just run vnc-server, to get the same effect. (MS-Windows does not have the choice of the other type of vnc-server). The over end needs a vnc-client. These exist for most Unixes, MS-Windows, MacOS, android, ...

Comment: Oh ok welI dont think I need to go that deep I just figured it out with screen and that seemed to work. Thanks again